How to find the k distance using pocketken.h3
I'm trying to find h3 indexes inside a radius and im using pocketken.h3 library. below is the code im using.
I was following this documentation to find the 'k' value.
  var edgeLength = zipH3Index.EdgeLengthKilometers();
  var radiusToHexagonRatio = radius / edgeLength;
  double k = Math.Sqrt(((Math.Pow(radiusToHexagonRatio, 2) - 1) / 3));
  var neighbors = zipH3Index.GridDiskDistances((int)Math.Ceiling(k));

But i'm getting the edgeLength as '0' to isolate this problem you can use this below code and it also gives 0 for edge length
 var index = new H3Index("89283080dcbffff");
   var length = index.EdgeLengthKilometers(); // 0

